# Why does YouTube's V3 API duplicate response data inside of a "result" object?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I'm calling YouTube's V3 API like so:

```
//  Expects options: { channelId: string, success: function, error: function };
getChannelTitle: function (options) {

    var request = GoogleAPI.client.youtube.channels.list({
        part: 'snippet',
        id: options.channelId,
        fields: 'items/snippet/title'
    });

    this._executeRequest({
        request: request,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log("response:", response);
            options.success(response.items[0].snippet.title);
        }
    });
},

_executeRequest: function (options) {
    options.request.execute(function (response) {
        if (!response.error) {
            options.success(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Everything works as expected, but the response from the request is a bit interesting:

[image]

Why is all of the response information duplicates inside of a "result" object? I don't see this from the API explorer: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.channels.list?part=snippet&id=UC_Gkp1Oa7e2a8NNaf5-KCpA&fields=items%252Fsnippet%252Ftitle&_h=5&